# Why can't I scroll to the bottom?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a function that triggers scrolling to the very bottom of the page *without* an animation.

```
function scroll() {
$(document).scrollTop(500); 
}
```

The above code works.

```
function scroll() {
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
}
```

**Why doesn't the above code work...**

Comment: But it DOES work, for example right on this page, if you call it on the console. Try first printing the height: `console.log($(document).height());`. What do you get? An error?

Comment: What does `$(document).height()` output? Did you check its value?

Comment: You might also have an error on your code, above the mentioned code, so that it will never reach those lines.

Comment: It works and outputs 1467.

Comment: your code is working just checked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).scrollTop(document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
```

Also tested

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the above code should work. For some odd reason, it doesn't work. I did this:

I had a PHP while loop that creates new id. I then used JS to go to a new URL. For example:

```
<div class='box' id='1' limit='2'> One </div>
<div class='box'id='2' limit='2'> Two </div>
```

Go to URL:

```
var limit = $(".box").parseInt($(this).attr("limit"));
window.open("courses.php#"+limit, "_self");
```